# How to get useful errors to debug rails email on staging/production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I've been following the Ruby on Rails Book by Michael Hartl and am trying to setup [Email in production](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-%20email_in_production) as described [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-%20email_in_production).  The difference is that I'm using my own cPanel server instead of heroku with the sendgrid addon.

The problem is that every time I try to create a new user via the /signup form on the server I get the following unhelpful message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

I've tried to allow error reporting by: 
adding

> config.consider_all_requests_local       = true

to my environments/staging.rb 
and I've also set

> config.log_level = :debug

which I think is the most verbose error level.

I've even tried changing- the staging server's environment to

> RailsEnv development

in Apache's included config.  But I still only get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message when trying to /signup a new user account.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing the environment setting with Apache's include config file to

> RailsEnv staging

enabled helpful errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use few gems to check error on server as,

1. [Exception Notifier](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) - this will send an email with full error trace
2. [Rails Exception Handler](https://github.com/Sharagoz/rails_exception_handler) - this allows us to store ruby/rails exception in database and also to customize error page